# Badge image inconsistent when on profile view

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I have recently realized that when visiting an account page then scrolling down to other accounts, the badges will look as if they were all from the current site.

IE: The photo above was taken from my bag on Arquad site and represents this bug. All badges are represented as coins rather than the look of their own sites. '

I am not 100% sure this is what the engineers of StackExchange are looking for so I am just pointing it out.

Thanks.
[image: This should be changed]

Answer (score 1):

The badges are intended to look consistent within a given site, so we always use the styling and images from the site you're on rather than other sites you have a profile on.